# empty collection when it should be populated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

A controller in my spring mvc app is giving an empty `concepts` collection for a `DrugWord` entity when there are `DrugConcept`s in the database for every `DrugWord`.  How can I change my code so that it populates the `concepts` collection with the appropriate number of `DrugConcept` instances for each `DrugWord` instance?

Here is the JPA code that queries the database:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public DrugWord findDrugWord(String wrd) {
    System.out.println("..... wrd is: "+wrd);
    return (DrugWord) em.find(DrugWord.class, wrd);
}
```

Here is the code for the relevant controller method, which prints out 0 for the size of `sel_word.getConcepts().size()` when the size should be at least 1:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/medications", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processFindForm(@RequestParam(value="wordId", required=false) String word, Patient patient, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Collection<DrugWord> results = this.clinicService.findDrugWordByName("");
    System.out.println("........... word is: "+word);
    if(word==null){word="abacavir";}
    model.put("words", results);
    DrugWord sel_word = this.clinicService.findDrugWord(word);
    System.out.println(";;;; sel_word.concepts.size(), sel_word.getName() are: "+sel_word.getConcepts().size()+", "+sel_word.getName());
    model.put("sel_word", sel_word);
    return "medications/medsList";
}
```

Is the problem that I only have GET programmed?  Would the problem be solved if I had a PUT method? If so, what would the PUT method need to look like?

**NOTE: To keep this posting brief, I have uploaded some relevant code to a file sharing site.  You can view the code by clicking on the following links:**
The code for the `DrugWord` entity is [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/tctgLNYsiYOT2hfR1sQa?b=mUukmtwPJsjWinfmqibA).
The code for the `DrugConcept` entity is [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/Mw2u2hlpLN1v74hcb4ZA?b=El4GUbL2j8XMkqxQWh65).
The code for the `DrugAtom` entity is [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/xJm4Nu6PHvY2zxNx1lw5?b=535W6SJlOcxoWCgaqncH).
The code to create the underlying data tables in MySQL is [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/6qyP2yVQ9bMvcLOCQHzd?b=b6Z77llFcwPgnvUeIPSg).
The code to populate the underlying data tables [is at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/zpUaYa36Ns22zZvSjZ00?b=1vCTLYSGm1puoz4KVaUT).
The data for one of the tables [is at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/EtzWGlhiuEhAWC3riAQy?b=OlQIYNaB6sPQg86Eh4oA).
Some representative data from a second table is [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/7DixpJLx1De04buPNnU2?b=amaYCLhWVSt9tgniFgpD).(This is just 10,000 records from the table, which has perhaps 100,000 rows.)
The data for the third table [is at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/vFMY6A7EFMeSajIg47nu?b=BL9D4QvPz11U2iZTMP3q). (This is a big file, may take a few moments to load.)
The persistence xml file can be read [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/3o7GkWX2iE6nTQMBLmSj?b=jMMGxh4Jr1JJtJNUqEit).

To help people visualize the underlying data, I am including a print screen of the top 2 results of queries showing data in the underlying tables as follows:

[image]

Comment: On what operating system does that not work??? I see that you work on Windows, does the mapping not work also on Windows or is it on a *nix OS?

Comment: Show us your persistence.xml file.

Comment: @AndreiI I added a link to the persistence xml file to my original posting above. I am working on a windows machine.  I only have a windows machine, so windows is the only operating system on which I can test this.  Does this additional information help you isolate the problem? Can you get it to run on your computer?

Comment: On an *nix system the database tables in MySQL are case-sensitive, so you should change the table name `drugwordsconsoJunction` in DrugWord.concepts. In rest everything seems OK. So I believe you simply must debug... as Gerley mentioned.

Comment: @AndreiI Thank you for looking into this.  I put up a 125 point carrot(100 bounty + 15 accepted answer + 10 for +1) because I need someone to talk me through it step by step.  I also posted more than enough for someone to recreate this on their machine so that it can happen fast.  If I could do it without help, I would not have taken all these steps.

Comment: @AndreiI Thank you for offering to share screens.  If I knew you, I would take you up on it.  But this is a hacker site, and it is not a good practice to share screens with strangers on a hacker site. In the past, people have just used the stack overflow chat rooms to explain things.  If we keep trading messages here, a link to continue the conversation in chat will appear.  I want to learn how to do it myself, but we all reach dead ends from time to time.

Comment: @AndreiI If you find the problem with your debugger, it would only take a few minutes at that point to explain to me via chat how to find it in my debugger.  I am using eclipse and I have used the debugger before, though I am still a novice with it as I prefer to SYSO when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that the DB was corrupt, specifically that you had new lines characters in every word, so that the queries always returned an empty result. Besides there were some problems that very big graphs of entities were loaded from DB, triggering a lot of SQL queries.

Comment: Thank you and +lots (still counting)

Comment: Yes.  Your insights helped me shrink it down so that I can re-frame the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all you can change the findDrugWord method to be like:

```
public DrugWord findDrugWord(String wrd) { 
    em.find(DrugWord.class, wrd); 
}
```

Because word is the PK and you've already set fetching when you put `@ManyToMany` there. *I can imagine that the duplicate fetch definition confuses your JPA provider, but it won't help it that's for sure. :)*

**Secondly**, take a look at this line:

```
PropertyComparator.sort(sortedConcepts, new MutableSortDefinition("concept", true, true));
```

I can't see `concept` attribute in your `DrugConcept` entity. Didn't you want to write `rxcui`?
But if you really want to have it sorted every time, add `@OrderBy("rxcui ASC")`.
I wouldn't make any sort in place of an Entity's Collection. Especially without properly overridden hashCode and equals: You can't be sure how Spring sorts your Collection with reflection in the background which can lead to lot of headaches.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: What changes did you make exactly? Try to set detailed logging on the persistence provider to see the generated SQLs.

Comment: All right, set a breakpoint in `getConceptsInternal()` and check what that returns. I still have bad feelings about that sort.

Comment: :D I can't see anything besides that it's initialized. Does it have any values or not?

Comment: No it doesn't mean that. Try to be a little bit thorough than that. Look into the collection and check what's inside. If you wish, you can SYSO it.

Comment: 3 things and I've run out of ideas: turn on detailed logging on the provider and check the generated SQL; validate the SQL by running it manually; make sure you have the data in your DB

Comment: Seriously man, think first, why would it be hard?! Anyway I'd say your DB is empty or inconsistent or something like that. I'd bet you won't see any result if you run that SQL manually. Good luck.